# Error using HTML-Parser

Tags: objective-c, ios, html-parser

I'm trying to use Objective-C--HMTL Parser (https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser).
I followed all the instructions carefully and in a new project works fine, but when I try to use it in another I get these errors:

[error screenshot](http://www.partisani.net/errore.jpg)

The difference between the two projects is that in the second I use "libsqlite3.dylib".

Thanks, Luigi.

Comment: add libxml2.dylib in your project

Comment: It is added but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you didnt import the .m files correctly, you will need to check that HTMLparser.m is included in the compile sources of your project

check screen shot [image]

Compile sources should include `HTMLParser.m`